# AVG antivirus free repeatedly detects my own program as a virus

Tags: anti-virus, avg-antivirus

More or less every time I start my program from Visual C# 2010 Express, AVG pops up saying it's found a virus. My program is a game and doesn't even access the filesystem!

Apparently the reason is "General Behaviour" which means nothing to me :D

Is there any way to stop it detecting the program? I've added exceptions, but I think that does nothing as the program often changes and it asks me again. I've added an exception for the bin folder, but that seems to only affect scans...

Comment: Add the location of your program to the list of files that won't be scanned by AVG then submit your program to AVG as a false positive.

Comment: AVG has just too many false positives. After [reporting your program](https://secure.avg.com/submit-sample), consider [switching to a different antivirus](http://www.av-comparatives.org/comparatives-reviews/).

Comment: Problem is, I'm developing it so it constantly changes; there wouldn't be much point in submitting it if I change it very soon after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude your program from AVG scanning.
You can see how to do this [here](http://www.avg.com/ww-en/faq.num-3489#num-3489)

> 1. Open the AVG program.
> 2. Double-click the Resident Shield component.
> 3. Click the Manage exceptions button.
> 4. In the newly opened dialog, please click either the Add Path or the Add File button to add the needed exception.
> 5. Click OK to confirm the changes.

Comment: The free version of AVG I'm running (AVG AntiVirus 2015), when creating an Exception (in Options > Advanced > Exceptions), allows the user to specify that AVG must ignore the specified file even when the file has been changed or updated. There is also an option to ignore the file if it is moved to a new location. And you can create two exceptions for a file, so as to specify both types of Exception for it. Although I am happy with AVG AntiVirus 2015, I recommend avoiding AVG AntiVirus 2017 (too many unhelpful changes have been made). Get the older version (e.g. from www.itechtics.com).